# Can you identify this Black Plane or Spaceship with black arches for wings?

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help me to ID this incomplete LEGO set?  It looks like a black plane or spaceship to me.

[image: black plane 1]
[image: black plane 2]

Answer (score 6):

This is not a set,

The [Tile 2 x 2 with Gold Crown on Light Bluish Gray Background Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3068bpb0789&in=S)  comes from [70404-1: King's Castle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70404-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

the [Brick, Arch 1 x 5 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2339#T=C) in Black does not appear in this set so it is probably a part of a MOC

Comment: The Arch's are probably of [7782-1: The Batwing: The Joker's Aerial Assault](https://brickset.com/sets/7782-1/The-Batwing-The-Joker-s-Aerial-Assault)

Comment: As it turns out, it actually is part of a set. The stickered tile and other plates was just throwing off the search.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely the base of the Batwing from [7782-1: The Batwing: The Joker's Aerial Assault](https://brickset.com/sets/7782-1/The-Batwing-The-Joker-s-Aerial-Assault) with a few random plates and tiles added on.

[image]

You can see from page 26 and 32 of [the instructions](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4492752.pdf) that the structures are the same.

[image]

[image]

There are just a few plates added on top what do not belong, perhaps because someone started to build a MOC based on the Batwing's structure.